# How to Create RSS Feeds for categories in Wordpress?

Tags: rss, feed

I want to create RSS feed for categories in WordPress.Is this possible? How could I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category feeds are a part of WordPress core. e.g. for category `foobar`, the RSS feed link is:

```
www.example.com/category/foobar/feed
```

Easy-peasy!

Comment: But @chip, I got "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." and <rss></rss> codes. Where is problem?